# Как через xpath найти строку, содержащую определенный текст?

Tags: c#, xpath

Есть кусок html-кода

```
<div class="sp-head folded"><span>Особенности RePack'a</span></div>
<div class="sp-body">
» Ничего не вырезано<br>`
Ничего не перекодировано<br>
» Путь сохранений игры: %SystemDrive%\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\LocalLow\Kowai Sugoi Studios\Shiver<br>
» Присутствует файл контрольных сумм<br>
» Версия игры: 1.0<br>
» Время установки: ~15 секунд<br>
» Релиз от Other s</div>
```

Мне нужно получить значение автора Репака. Т.е. `Other s`

Я представляю, как это реализовать через `substring`, но стало интересно можно ли вытащить это значение через xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
//div[@class='sp-body']/text()[substring-after(., "Other")]
```

дальше сами

upd

```
substring-after(//div[@class='sp-body']/text()[substring-before(., "Релиз")], "Релиз от " )
```

и его вывод `"Other s"`

Comment: подсказка здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322013/getting-a-substring-of-an-attribute-in-xpath